# How to get stream object identified by a FILE?

Tags: c++, iostream

Documentation states that `FILE` is object type that identifies a stream. So, is it possible to get the stream object associated with a `FILE`?

For example, I'd like to get `std::cout` object from `stdout` `FILE` pointer, or `std::cerr` from `stderr` etc. More generally I want to write a function that redirects a given stream and sets the custom `streambuf` to it, something like this:

```
void redirect(FILE* file, std::ios stream) {
    freopen_s((FILE**)file, "CONOUT$", "w", file);
    stream.rdbuf(customBuffer);
}
```

used to redirect streams

```
redirect(stdout, std::cout);
redirect(stderr, std::cerr);
```

It seems redundant to have 2 parameters, since both parameters are always associated with each other.

Comment: Why not use file streams in the first place?

Comment: I want my function to operate on all I/O streams, not just std::fstream, so it can also redirect standard streams.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard library includes the C standard library. A `FILE` is a C stream, which is quite a different animal than a C++ iostream. It is possible for an `std::stream` implementation to rely of an underlying `FILE`, but this is not required by the standard, and even in that case there is no way to retrieve it.

What is possible is to build a custom `std::streambuf` that explicitly uses an underlying `FILE *`, and use it in a `std::stream`. `std::basic_streambuf` is one of the few classes from the C++ standard library that is explicitely designed as a base class for custom derivation. Unfortunately I could not find a tutorial for it, but the class contains a number of virtual methods that you just have to override. It is not exactly an easy path, but is possible with some works, heavy testing, and eventually some help from SO if you get stuck somewhere. But a full implementation is far beyond a SO answer.

TL/DR: there is no underlying `std::stream` associated with a `FILE` but with some work you can build a custom `stream_buffer` that will use an underlying `FILE *`. Though those are rather advanced operations...

Answer (score 0):

While it is not possible to cleanly do this in C++ you could do something like this.

```
FILE * file = popen("someFile")
const unsigned BUFF = 2048;
string total;
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    vector<char> cBuf[BUFF];
    size_t read = fread((void *)&cBuf[0], 1, BUFF, f);
    if (read) 
    { 
        total.append(cBuf.begin(), cBuf.end()); 
    }
    if (read < BUFF) 
    { 
        done = true; 
    }
}
pclose(f);
istringstream filey(total);
```

Hope this helps.